# Wordpress share core directories using symbolic links

Tags: linux, wordpress, hyperlink, symlink

### Backgrounds:

I'm deploying several (about 10) wordpress sites in a single ubuntu-server.

For each, I have a single mysql database (single schema), and a single wordpress file directories.

For each instance of wordpress directories, the structure is like the below:

```
|-- wp-admin
|   |-- css
|   |-- images
|   |-- includes
|   |-- js
|   |-- maint
|   |-- meta
|   |-- network
|   `-- user
|-- wp-content
|   |-- cache
|   |-- languages
|   |-- plugins
|   |-- themes
|   |-- upgrade
|   `-- uploads
`-- wp-includes
    |-- certificates
    |-- css
    |-- fonts
    |-- ID3
    |-- images
    |-- js
    |-- pomo
    |-- SimplePie
    |-- Text
    `-- theme-compat
```

So I found that the `wp-admin` and `wp-content` directories is redundant, because they're wordpress core part, I will never change them manually.

To reduce the space of these parts, I keep one instance, and for the others, I created symbolic links on them.

---

For example, I have one base instance first:

```
/var/www/wordpress/
```

And one of mysite:

```
/var/www/site1/
```

I change the structure using these commands:

```
$ cd /var/www/site1
$ rm -rf wp-admin
$ rm -rf wp-includes
$ ln -s /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin ./
$ ln -s /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes ./
```

Well, I run the `site1`, it effects.

---

### Problem:

After this, I'm not able to enter the admin panel.

When I navigate to: `http://mysite.mydomain.com`.

It redirect to the login page, and no matter what I was entering (I can make sure the username and password are correct), it cannot login.

It seems the session cannot create correctly, can anyone point out what's the matter here?

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try mounting the folders instead of using symbolic link. Something similar to this

```
mount --bind /var/www/wordpres/wp-admin /var/www/site1/wp-admin
```

make sure you have the directory created before you mount. If this works for you then make sure you have the mount in your /etc/fstab

Comment: Wow, perfectly worked for me! Forgive my poor linux skill. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, is there any way to skip these mounted directories when copying? I want to reduce the backup size, too. Or I can only remove those part manually? Thank you!

Comment: It would probably depend on how you backup. I would say exclusion would be the easiest through the software you use.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @madmanali93's answer, we can add a record to `/etc/fstab` to auto mount that directory on boot:

```
/var/www/wordpress/wp-admin /var/www/site1/wp-admin none bind 0 0
```